# Doxywizard cannot find latex

Tags: macos, latex, doxygen, doxywizard

When I attempt to run doxywizard on a module with commands for LaTeX, e.g. (Fortran):

```
!> @brief
!> Here's some stuff for LaTeX: @f$(Foo)@f$

module Foo
...
```

I get two errors in the log file:

```
...
Generating bitmaps for formulas in HTML...
sh: latex: command not found
error: Problems running latex. Check your installation or look for typos in _formulas.tex and check _formulas.log!
Generating image form_0.png for formula
sh: dvips: command not found
error: Problems running dvips. Check your installation!
Generating index page...
...
```

`latex` is located in /usr/local/bin, which is in my path, and `dvips` is in /Library/TeX/texbin, which is also in my path, and both execute from a terminal.  I've also attempted setting
LATEX_CMD_NAME = /usr/local/bin/latex
to no avail.  If I run `doxygen` from the command line with the Doxyfile generated by the wizard, the LaTeX is generated correctly, so it just seems to be a problem with the wizard.  Is there another way to tell the wizard where how to find the `latex` command?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Are you starting the doxywizard from a terminal window or by a "double click"?

Comment: I'm running 1.8.15 and via a double click.  I did just try running from the terminal and it worked.  That set off a light bulb that it's probably a global path issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running `doxywizard` from the finder, it uses the globally set path, not the path set in the `$HOME/.bashrc`.  Thus, there are a number of solutions, including adding `/usr/local/bin`, et al., to the global path (`/etc/bashrc`) or creating a link in `/usr/local/bin` to `/Applications/Doxygen.app/Contents/MacOS/Doxywizard`, and always running the wizard from the terminal, which is the option I chose.